# Какой это стиль и почему? Научный или научно-публицистический?

Tags: стилистика, стили-речи

Помогите, пожалуйста, определить стиль. Думаю, научный или все же научно-публицистический? Сомневаюсь с ответом. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Научно-публицистический бывает? Не бывает – бывают научный и публицистический. Это научный, никаких сомнений.